# Raycast not detecting custom Unity UI button script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have written a custom class to create buttons which can have an animator. But objects of this class are not detectable by raycast but normal Unity UI buttons are detectable by raycast. I'm looking for a solution which can be solved through code.

```
public class AnimatedButton : UIBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [Serializable]
    private class ButtonClickedEvent : UnityEvent
    {
    }

    public bool Interactable = true;

    [SerializeField]
    private ButtonClickedEvent onClick = new ButtonClickedEvent();

    private Animator animator;

    private bool blockInput;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (!Interactable || eventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
            return;

        if (!blockInput)
        {
            blockInput = true;
            Press();
            // Block the input for a short while to prevent spamming.
            StartCoroutine(BlockInputTemporarily());
        }
    }

    public void Press()
    {
        if (!IsActive())
            return;

        animator.SetTrigger("Pressed");
        StartCoroutine(InvokeOnClickAction());
    }

    private IEnumerator InvokeOnClickAction()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        onClick.Invoke();
    }

    private IEnumerator BlockInputTemporarily()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        blockInput = false;
    }
}
```

below code is used to find the gameobject by firing a raycast

```
private bool checkButtonClick()
{
    bool flag = false;
    PointerEventData pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    List<RaycastResult> raycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();
    
    pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResult);
    foreach (RaycastResult result in raycastResult)
    {
        if (result.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() != null || result.gameObject.GetComponent<AnimatedButton>() != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Button Name : " + result.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
    raycastResult.Clear();
    return flag;
}
```

Only objects of type "Button" are printed with this log and objects of type "AnimatedButton" are not detected. What could be the issue here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. But it's not `UIBehaviour`, it's actually `UnityEngine.UI.Graphic`, derived from `UIBehaviour`, that is searched for by the `GraphicRaycaster`. So you should be able to derive from `Graphic`, and your new button type will be found in the raycast results. Here's the Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) relating to the `Graphic` class. Quoting that page:

> Base class for all visual UI Component.
>
> When creating visual UI components you should inherit from this class.

Comment: Thank you, You are correct. But when I try to inherit from Graphic the issue I'm facing is that I'm getting exceptions for canvas renderer not being attached to the object. If I try add a canvas renderer run time, in some cases I'm getting an white border like thing for the buttons. So is there any other way around it ?

Comment: @Zenhal I'm not quite sure why you'd be getting a white border around some items. Is that what your next issue is? Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're asking when you ask "is there any other way around it". We could also look at why you're creating a new item, AniamtedButton, from such a low level class. Could you extend `Button` instead, or even `UnityEngine.UI.Selectable`?